# Identify the error in the problem related to birthday paradox.

Tags: probability

Consider the simple problem below. I know solution method 1 is correct. But where am I going wrong in methods 2 and 3?

> Three people each choose a random number between 1 and 100. What is
>   the probability that no two of them have picked the same number?

**Method 1:**

Each person has to choose a different number from the previous person.

$\therefore P = \frac{100}{100} \times \frac{99}{100} \times \frac{98}{100} = 0.9702$

**Method 2:**

$P($No two persons choose same number$) = 1 - P($At least two persons choose same number$)$

Number of pairs of two persons = $\binom{3}{2}$ = 3

$P($At least two persons choose same number$)$ = P(1st pair chooses same number OR 2nd pair chooses same number OR 3rd pair chooses same number)

$\therefore P = 1 - (\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}) = 0.97$

**Method 3:**

$P($No two persons choose same number$) = 1 - P($Each pair of two persons choose different numbers$)$

Number of pairs of two persons = $\binom{3}{2}$ = 3

$P($Each pair of two persons choose different numbers$)$ = P(1st pair chooses different numbers AND 2nd pair chooses different numbers AND 3rd pair chooses different numbers)

$\therefore P = \frac{99}{100}\times\frac{99}{100}\times\frac{99}{100} = 0.970299$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 2:**
Every time you count that a pair chose the same number, you are also counting the possibility all three of them choose the same number.
[image]
That way you count the case all three chose the same number 3 times so to correct for that you need to subtract $2P(\textrm{All three chose the same number}).$
$$P=1-\left(\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}+2\cdot\frac{1}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{100}\right)$$

**Method 3:**
As others have mentioned, these probabilities are not independent (see the overlap in the picture above) so you can't just multiply them like that. While method 2 had an easy fix, fixing this would simply lead you to method 1. 
$$P=P(\textrm{1st pair chooses different numbers})P(\textrm{3rd person chooses a different number from the other two})=\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{98}{100}$$

Answer (score 0):

In solution #2, the case where all three people choose the same number is counted in all three of your cases. This is why you get a lower probability.

In solution #3, similarly because all three people could choose the same number, your probabilities are not independent, so you can't multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2:
P(At least two persons choose same number) = P(exactly two choose the same number) + P(exactly three choose the same number).

Method 3:
P(no two persons choose the same number) --- this was done in a straightforward way in your Method 1; be that as it may, this would be (indirectly),

$1$ - P(exactly two people choose the same number) - P(exactly three people choose the same number).